# How to search by words written together among data where these words are written apart in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I have documents which have, let's say, 1 field - *name* of this document. Name may consist of several words written apart, for example:

```
{
    "name": "first document"
},
{
    "name": "second document"
}
```

My goal is to be able to search for these documents by strings:

```
firstdocument, seconddocumen
```

As you can see, search strings are written wrong, but they still match those documents if we delete whitespaces from documents' names. This issue could be handled by creating another field with the same string but without whitespaces, but it seems like extra data unless there's no other way to do that.

I need something similar to this:

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "whitespace",
  "filter": [ 
    {
       "type":"shingle",
       "max_shingle_size":3,
       "min_shingle_size":2,
       "output_unigrams":"true",
       "token_separator": ""
    }
  ],
  "text": "first document"
}
```

But the other way around. I need kind of apply this not to a search text, but for search objects (name of documents), so I could find documents with a little misspell in a search text. How should it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) with an analyzer for removing whitespaces.

**Analyzer**

```
"no_spaces": {
  "filter": [
    "lowercase"
  ],
  "char_filter": [
    "remove_spaces"
  ],
  "tokenizer": "standard"
}
```

**Char Filter**

```
"remove_spaces": {
  "type": "pattern_replace",
  "pattern": "[ ]",
  "replacement": ""
}
```

**Field Mapping**

```
"name": {
  "type": "text",
  "fields": {
    "without_spaces": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "no_spaces"
    }
  }
}
```

**Query**

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name.without_spaces": {
        "query": "seconddocumen",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

For completion: An alternative to the `remove_spaces` filter could be the shingle filter:

```
"analysis": {
  "filter": {
    "shingle_filter": {
      "type": "shingle",
      "output_unigrams": "false",
      "token_separator": ""
    }
  },
  "analyzer": {
    "shingle_analyzer": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "standard",
      "filter": [
        "shingle_filter"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```